# Install certificate on Apache using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-cloudformation

I have a got a certificate imported in Amazon certificate manager. It is signed by Digicert and will be used on ec2 instances hosting Apache web server. Once I imported the certificate, I got an ARN but I am unable to figure out how to use the ARN to install the certificate on ec2 instance using cloudformation? 
I have read some docs on the internet and the suggestion is to import the .crt and .key file and then adding directives to httpd.conf file. 
Has anyone tried getting certificate from ACM and then installing on ec2 instance using cloudformation? What were the challenges and how did you overcome those?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html could be useful, but why do you want to install using cloudformation?

Comment: I am deploying couple of instances using cloudformation, part of the process will take care of installing Apache on those instances.
I also wanted to install the certificate as part of the cloudformation so that I dont have to do manual installation and configuration of the certificate. Everything suing one cloudformation template.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up following this thread [How to install SSL certificate on a single instance ELB enviroment](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=130409)
Worked for me, hopefully it will help someone else
NB: Strictly for testing purposes only

Comment: The URL is not working, do you remember what was the solution?